# Trying to publish ASP.NET Core React app with Electron.NET

Tags: electron.net

So my understanding from the documentation to perform a publish is I need to call 'electronize build /target win'. This builds the project. However, there are some issues I'm unsure how to address.

1. The content path when I try to run it says the content root is C:\Windows\system32 instead of the actual working directory where the .exe resides. That isn't correct. Any ideas why? I think some of the other issues are caused by this.

   Edit: I found out #1 uses the correct directory if it is ran as administrator. Unsure why.
2. How does one hide the command menu that comes up? all i want is the electron window to show on publish.
3. I see an electron window come up like when i run 'electronize start' but not after publishing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the latest version of Electron.NET. During development, a development menu is displayed. A standard behavior of Electron if you not have your own menu. With a build, the development menu is hidden again.